# Own Laravel directive to store data in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Is there a elegant way to create a [own Blade directive](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#extending-blade) which acts like a stack array? I know of the `@push` directive I could use like `@push('key', 'value')` but the value just gets append, what I need would be a stack array which I could retrieve as variable in another view (in my case the layout). Example (`home.blade.php`):

```
@ownDirective('key', 'value1')
@ownDirective('key', 'value2')
```

And then `layout.blade.php`:

```
{{ dd($key) }} // ['value1', 'value2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to achieve what I need:

```
Blade::directive('addstack', function ($expression) {
    list($name, $value) = explode(',', $expression);
    return "<?php {$name}[] = {$value}; ?>";
});

// Usage:
// @addstack($key, 'value1')
// @addstack($key, 'value2')
```